# Fold and Homoclinic bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have a question of the positioning of bifurcation lines in 2D-parameterspace.

say we have a system of ODE's with two bifurcation parameters.

My understanding of the bifurcation lines is that the Fold line should contain the Homoclinic, and that they only tangentially meet in a Takens Bogdanov bifurcation point, but don't cross.

Is this true?